# Spacetime manifolds of 1+1 d systems for writing TQFT partition functions

Tags: spacetime, topology, topological-field-theory

Are the spacetime manifolds of two unentangled systems disconnected?

This arises in the context of thinking of an operator whose expectation value we wish to take by writing this quantity in terms of a TQFT partition function of a 1+1 d system and its copy (the two-copy thing is done in defining the swap operator in https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2335). So in order to think about the partition function of this two-copy system as a whole, and have the possibility of spacetime flux insertions, how does one visualize the corresponding 1+1 d spacetime manifold?